# How to import a library into a Arduino program?

Tags: arduino, programming, processing

I have a Arduino program wich make use of the processing library.

The program code starts with

```
import processing.serial.*;
```

When I try to compile it with the Arduino compiler it crashes with

```
'import' does not name a file
```

The code I want to execute is http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-an-RGB-Led-with-Arduino-and-Processing/

I pasted the serial library folder from processing into the same folder as my code. But it still crashes.

---

**Update:**
My assumptions were wrong! The code I tried to use was designed for Java and to be used with the [Processing IDE](http://processing.org/) not the Arduino IDE. It works fine now with Processing! And the other part of the code works fine with the Arduino IDE :)

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Window 7

Comment: can you post the code from instrucables, some people do not have accounts and cannot access those files, it would help greatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like you are using Java. Or are you using the Arduino IDE.

```
import processing.serial.*;
```

looks like Java code. If you are using the Arduino IDE it won't accept that command.

To import a library in C, the command is `#include`.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up something! The code is java and is interpreted by Processing and not Arduino, updated the description.

Comment: kein ding, läuft ;)

Comment: Ja, es funkt! ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Arduino language, libraries are included like

```
#include <OneWire.h>
```

etc

And the code you are asking about is for **Processing**
You should paste it there.

If you want just to control RGB led, you can use my code:

```
    /*
  Serial RGB controller

 Reads a serial input string looking for three comma-separated
 integers with a newline at the end. Values should be between 
 0 and 255. The sketch uses those values to set the color 
 of an RGB LED attached to pins 9 - 11.

 The circuit:
 * Common-anode RGB LED cathodes attached to pins 9 - 11
 * LED anode connected to pin 13

 To turn on any given channel, set the pin LOW.  
 To turn off, set the pin HIGH. The higher the analogWrite level,
 the lower the brightness.

 created 29 Nov 2010
 by Tom Igoe

 MODIFIED by Semyon Tushev,
 February 2011

 This example code is in the public domain. 
 */

String inString = "";    // string to hold input
int currentColor = 0;
int red, green, blue = 0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial communications:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // set LED cathode pins as outputs:
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  // turn on pin 13 to power the LEDs:
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  int inChar;

  // Read serial input:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inChar = Serial.read();
  }

  if (isDigit(inChar)) {
    // convert the incoming byte to a char 
    // and add it to the string:
    inString += (char)inChar; 
  }

  // if you get a comma, convert to a number,
  // set the appropriate color, and increment
  // the color counter:
  if (inChar == ',') {
    // do something different for each value of currentColor:
    switch (currentColor) {
    case 0:    // 0 = red
      red = inString.toInt();
      // clear the string for new input:
      inString = ""; 
      break;
    case 1:    // 1 = green:
      green = inString.toInt();
      // clear the string for new input:
      inString = ""; 
      break;
    }
    currentColor++;
  }
  // if you get a newline, you know you've got
  // the last color, i.e. blue:
  if (inChar == '\n') {
    blue = inString.toInt();

    // set the levels of the LED.
    // subtract value from 255 because a higher
    // analogWrite level means a dimmer LED, since
    // you're raising the level on the anode:
    analogWrite(11,  blue);
    analogWrite(9,  red);
    analogWrite(10, green);



    // clear the string for new input:
    inString = ""; 
    // reset the color counter:
    currentColor = 0;

  }

}


/*
Here's a Processing sketch that will draw a color wheel and send a serial
string with the color you click on:

// Subtractive Color Wheel with Serial
// Based on a Processing example by Ira Greenberg. 
// Serial output added by Tom Igoe
// 
// The primaries are red, yellow, and blue. The secondaries are green, 
// purple, and orange. The tertiaries are  yellow-orange, red-orange, 
// red-purple, blue-purple, blue-green, and yellow-green.
// 
// Create a shade or tint of the subtractive color wheel using
// SHADE or TINT parameters.

// Updated 29 November 2010.



import processing.serial.*;

int segs = 12;
int steps = 6;
float rotAdjust = TWO_PI / segs / 2;
float radius;
float segWidth;
float interval = TWO_PI / segs;

Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  background(127);
  smooth();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  noStroke();
  // make the diameter 90% of the sketch area
  radius = min(width, height) * 0.45;
  segWidth = radius / steps;

  // swap which line is commented out to draw the other version
  // drawTintWheel();
  drawShadeWheel();
  // open the first serial port in your computer's list
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}


void drawShadeWheel() {
  for (int j = 0; j < steps; j++) {
    color[] cols = { 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, 255-(255/steps)*j, 0), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, (255/1.5)-((255/1.5)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, (255/2)-((255/2)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, (255/2.5)-((255/2.5)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, 0, 0), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, 0, (255/2)-((255/2)/steps)*j), 
      color(255-(255/steps)*j, 0, 255-(255/steps)*j), 
      color((255/2)-((255/2)/steps)*j, 0, 255-(255/steps)*j), 
      color(0, 0, 255-(255/steps)*j),
      color(0, 255-(255/steps)*j, (255/2.5)-((255/2.5)/steps)*j), 
      color(0, 255-(255/steps)*j, 0), 
      color((255/2)-((255/2)/steps)*j, 255-(255/steps)*j, 0)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < segs; i++) {
      fill(cols[i]);
      arc(width/2, height/2, radius, radius, 
      interval*i+rotAdjust, interval*(i+1)+rotAdjust);
    }
    radius -= segWidth;
  }
}


void drawTintWheel() {
  for (int j = 0; j < steps; j++) {
    color[] cols = { 
      color((255/steps)*j, (255/steps)*j, 0), 
      color((255/steps)*j, ((255/1.5)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color((255/steps)*j, ((255/2)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color((255/steps)*j, ((255/2.5)/steps)*j, 0), 
      color((255/steps)*j, 0, 0), 
      color((255/steps)*j, 0, ((255/2)/steps)*j), 
      color((255/steps)*j, 0, (255/steps)*j), 
      color(((255/2)/steps)*j, 0, (255/steps)*j), 
      color(0, 0, (255/steps)*j),
      color(0, (255/steps)*j, ((255/2.5)/steps)*j), 
      color(0, (255/steps)*j, 0), 
      color(((255/2)/steps)*j, (255/steps)*j, 0)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < segs; i++) {
      fill(cols[i]);
      arc(width/2, height/2, radius, radius, 
      interval*i+rotAdjust, interval*(i+1)+rotAdjust);
    }
    radius -= segWidth;
  }
}

void draw() {
  // nothing happens here
}

void mouseReleased() {
  // get the color of the mouse position's pixel:
  color targetColor = get(mouseX, mouseY);
  // get the component values:
  int r = int(red(targetColor));
  int g = int(green(targetColor));
  int b = int(blue(targetColor));
  // make a comma-separated string:
  String colorString = r + "," + g + "," + b + "\n";
  // send it out the serial port:
  myPort.write(colorString );
}


*/
```

It receives string like 100,255,80 via serial and sets the outputs. Don't forget to send newline characters as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a relative path to the library? like ~/proccessing/library/yourfile.* 
another suggestion is add the library to the Arduino library folder and not your project folder.